# git branching and committing -- can you explain the theory behind this puzzling (to me) behavior?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a master branch and everything is fine in it.  Then I create a branch called experimental and I create a new file.  While in my experimental branch I add this file using the `git add` command.  Then I checkout my master branch.  While in my master branch I run `git status` and discover that this file has also been added to my master branch.  I then run `git commit -m "message"` while in my master branch and the commit happens.  Then I switch to my experimental branch and run `git status` and discover that the file has also been committed in my experimental branch.

Here is what I would have expected: Upon switching to the master branch after adding the new file I would expect that the file would not appear there.  After all, I did not create the file while in the master branch and I did not add the file while in the master branch.  So when I switch to the master branch and run `git status` why does it find the file already added and ready to commit?  And when I then do commit it while in the master branch, why do I also find it committed in the experimental branch when I switch back?  Did it commit to two branches at once?

Comment: Just because `git status` doesn't show anything when you switch back to the experimental branch doesn't mean the file was committed in that branch.  It just means you don't have anything staged.

Comment: Well, it shows no untracked files and no staged files, so I guess the file was committed.

Comment: Use `git log` to find out what commits have been applied to your current branch. You'll probably find that the file was committed to your "master" branch, but not to your "experimental" branch.

Comment: Thanks.  Running git log shows two commits for the master branch, but only one for the exp branch.  So I guess in my exp branch I should now proceed as though the branch knows nothing about that file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `git add`, the file is *not* committed, it's only added to Git's "index". You probably wanted to run `git commit` after doing `git add` on your experimental branch.

When you switch branches in Git, the changes in your working directory *and in the index* are carried over as long as they don't conflict with any other files that change during the branch switch.

To address your specific concern:

> ...and discover that this file has also been added to my master branch.

If you haven't run `git commit`, then the file has not yet been added to *any* branch at all.

Comment: I did not run <code>git commit</code> before switching to the master branch, and I did not intend to.  However, when I switched to the master branch and ran <code>git status</code> it appeared as though the file had already been staged, even though I had staged it in the experimental branch and not in the master branch.  I think the confusion is due to the fact that I used the term "add" because you stage a file using the "add" command.

Comment: In Git, there is only one "index". When you `git add` a changed file, it goes into the index. It's not "staged for branch X" because there is not a separate index for each branch.